# Find Euler angel using SVM

Tags: svm, libsvm

I have to find the way to detect **Euler** angle of the object. There is **2000 pictures** of object in different position (like on the picture below) and my task is to find position of this object on the picture and the angle.

Angels: 0.3472, 0.6300, 12.1673
[image]

All of the pictures has described angles. As far I tried LibSVM I can recognize if object belong to class or not. But is it possible to find angle? 

I very beginner so every tutorial and advice would be nice.

So far I tried to recognize if object is a satellite or not..

Comment: Please be aware that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @honk is there another place where I can post question like this?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question would be appropriate for any SE site in its current form. It appears to be too broad. IMHO you are not providing enough information. An example image (including the expected result) would be nice and you should describe what you did with LibSVN and where and why you failed.

Comment: In case you consider to improve your question, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) again. This might help you to ask a better question.

Comment: @honk I am working on it

Comment: given that you already have features extracted from the images you would have to do three different SVR (support vector regression) models, one for each euler angle. I have no idea if that will work out.